# Repeating section headers in moderncv?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, moderncv

I am trying to prepare my CV using `moderncv`, and my publication list currently splits pages.  I would like the top of the next page to have `\refname{} (continued)` in the *same typeface as the original `\refname` callout*.

The closest I have gotten is with the `\afterpage` package, but this **(a)** requires that I know exactly what section is going to be at page breaks, which might change as I add/subtract things from my CV, and **(b)** does not work well with `bibliography` as it's a macro that creates a section and thus doesn't appear to like being interrupted.  The MWE I provide below comes close to what I want, but problems (a) and (b) above are apparent.

What can I do?

Here's the MWE (and the references for the .bib file are below that):

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}


\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{black}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


\name{John T.}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum vitae}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(555)~555~5890}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\interlinepenalty=10000 



\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
\section{Education}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\section{Awards and Honors}
    \cvitem{year}{Award}
    \cvitem{year}{Award}
    \cvitem{year}{Award}
    \cvitem{year}{Award}
    \cvitem{year}{Award}

\section{Teaching Positions}
    \cvitem{year}{course name}
    \cvitem{year}{course name}
    \cvitem{year}{course name}
    \cvitem{year}{course name}
    \cvitem{year}{course name}
    \cvitem{year}{course name}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Publications I Wish I had Written}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{gore2011}
\nocite{komatsu2011}
\nocite{lister2011}
\nocite{rasmussen2011}
\afterpage{\section{\refname{} (continued)}}

\bibliography{publications}

\end{document}
```

publications.bib:

```
@article{komatsu2011,
  title={Seven-year Wilkinson microwave anisotropy probe (WMAP) observations: cosmological interpretation},
  author={Komatsu, Eiichiro and Smith, KM and Dunkley, J and Bennett, CL and Gold, B and Hinshaw, G and Jarosik, N and Larson, D and Nolta, MR and Page, L and others},
  journal={The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series},
  volume={192},
  number={2},
  pages={18},
  year={2011},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@article{lister2011,
  title={Hotspots of aberrant epigenomic reprogramming in human induced pluripotent stem cells},
  author={Lister, Ryan and Pelizzola, Mattia and Kida, Yasuyuki S and Hawkins, R David and Nery, Joseph R and Hon, Gary and Antosiewicz-Bourget, Jessica and O’Malley, Ronan and Castanon, Rosa and Klugman, Sarit and others},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={471},
  number={7336},
  pages={68--73},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{gore2011,
  title={Somatic coding mutations in human induced pluripotent stem cells},
  author={Gore, Athurva and Li, Zhe and Fung, Ho-Lim and Young, Jessica E and Agarwal, Suneet and Antosiewicz-Bourget, Jessica and Canto, Isabel and Giorgetti, Alessandra and Israel, Mason A and Kiskinis, Evangelos and others},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={471},
  number={7336},
  pages={63--67},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{rasmussen2011,
  title={Structure of a nanobody-stabilized active state of the [bgr] 2 adrenoceptor},
  author={Rasmussen, S{\o}ren GF and Choi, Hee-Jung and Fung, Juan Jose and Pardon, Els and Casarosa, Paola and Chae, Pil Seok and DeVree, Brian T and Rosenbaum, Daniel M and Thian, Foon Sun and Kobilka, Tong Sun and others},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={469},
  number={7329},
  pages={175--180},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Still one bug left, but hopefully someone else can figure it out :)

Here is my idea: close the `thebibliography` environment at the start of every `\bibitem` to reopen it immediately. This way, LaTeX will print the bibliography head through `\bibliographyhead` between every bib item.

Then it *should* be a simple matter of modifying `\bibliographyhead` to only print something when a new conditional, `\ifbibliographyhead`, is set to `true`. We can then set it to `true` initially, set it to `false` every time the header is printed, and use `\afterpage` to set it again to `true` at the beginning of every page.

Here is the code:

```
\makeatletter
\let\refname@original\refname
\newif\ifbibliographyhead\bibliographyheadtrue% define a new conidtional and set it to "true" initially
\def\bibliographyhead#1{%
  % print the header only if \ifbibliographyhead is set to "true"
  \ifbibliographyhead%
    \section{#1}%
    \global\bibliographyheadfalse% set the conditional to false after every header printout
    \gdef\refname{\refname@original{} (cont'd)}% update the header title to add " (cont'd)"
  \fi}
\let\bibitem@original\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
%  \ifbibliographyhead% if you uncomment this line and the following \fi, the "(cont'd)" heading jumps a bib item further (?!)
    \end{thebibliography}%
    \begin{thebibliography}{1}%
%  \fi
  \bibitem@original{#1}}
\makeatother
% at the start of every new page, reset the new conditional to "true"
\afterpage{\global\bibliographyheadtrue}
```

Unfortunately, somehow the first `\bibitem` of the new page doesn't show the header, only the second one. I don't understand why --- yet...

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm not very good with if statements in TeX yet, so I can't further improve your suggestion. Is there a way to "lag" the conditional by 1? That is, can it be set to TRUE if  the next item is at the top, rather than the current item?

Comment: @DocBuckets This can be done through the `aux` file, you can write a line in this file for every entry in the bibliography. Well, you actually don't need to do it yourself, I believe that this is what `\bibitem` does anyways. Second possibility, it is possible to enforce a page break if there's not enough space on the current page (search for `pagegoal` on the site to see various examples of its usage).